# Submit a form if the statement is true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, form-submit

I am trying to write a very simple jQuery function which will have two main properties. The first one will be to check if the field is empty or not. The second one will be if the field is not empty to execute a form which will lead to a PHP coded page. I am very new to jQuery and I will be very grateful if someone can point where exactly is my mistake. Thank you in advance.

```js
function Captcha() {
  $('#Button').click(function() {
    if ($("#Field").val().length == 0) {
      alert("Please fill the box");
      return false;
    } else {
      alert("Your code is saved");
      return true;
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  Captcha();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="success.php" id="Alpha" method="post" onsubmit="return Captcha();">
  <input id="Field" type="text" placeholder="Enter key here">
  <button id="Button" type="submit" form="Alpha">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

Comment: what's wrong with what you posted? checked your console and html source? error reporting? etc.

Comment: Don't work with the button's `click` event, work with the form's `submit` event.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The problem is that it doesn't want to redirect me to the 'success.php' even if the field is filled and it returned the true statement.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you for the advice, will definitely do that. Unfortunately, I think that in this particular case even if I change it the problem will be unresolved.

Comment: See my answer below for a working version.

Comment: *"it doesn't want to redirect me to the 'success.php'"* - redirect?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am not sure how to explain. If you check Scott Markus' answer you will see what I tried to achieve.

Comment: @GeorgeStoqnov I see. The "redirect" kind of threw me off ;-) Glad you got your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't work with the button's `click` event, work with the form's `submit` event because a form can be submitted via the keyboard and therefore the button can be circumvented.

You can see a working version **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/ax50g9xf/2/)** (Stack Overflow prevents submit code from working in the snippet environment below.)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#Alpha').on("submit", function() {
    if ($("#Field").val().length == 0) {
      alert("Please fill the box");
      return false;
    } else {
      alert("Your code is saved");
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="success.php" id="Alpha" method="post" onsubmit="return Captcha();">
  <input id="Field" type="text" placeholder="Enter key here">
  <button id="Button" type="submit" form="Alpha">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you very much for the help and for the advice about using the form submit instead of buttons. I owe you a big one!

Answer (score 2):

You would want to validate the form fields when you actually submit the form. When you click on the button you are still in the process of triggering the submit.

Try changing this:

```
$('#Button').click(function() {
```

Into this:

```
$('#Alpha').on('submit', function() {
```

See if that helps.

Comment: I saw where my mistake is, thank you very much for pointing it out.